# Creating a Trigger so that a member is not allowed to rent more than 5 movies at a given time

Tags: sql, database, oracle, triggers

I want to create a trigger. A customer can rent up to a maximum five videos at any one time(allow no more than five checked out videos at any time) Below is my attempt at the scenario. What can I do to make it work? Thanks!

```
Create or Replace Trigger Rent_5_Rule
Before insert on Member
For each Row
Declare
NofTransactions binary_integer;

Begin
select Count(*)
into NofTransactions
From Transaction
where Mem_Num :new.Mem_num AND Vid_Num is Null;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(NofTransactions);
IF(NofTransactions+1) > then
Raise_application_error(-20002, 'Exceed max number of Videos allowed');
end if;
end;
/
show error;
```

Comment: We're generally happy to help people with homework assignments.  However, you're much more likely to get a response if your question includes your good-faith attempted answer along with whatever error(s) that answer produces or whatever behavior(s) it has that you don't want.  Otherwise, your question becomes too broad because we have no idea what concepts you understand and what stumbling blocks you have.

Comment: I have gone ahead with my best guess and posted it at the bottom. Oracle doesn't like my method though. What can I change to this?

Comment: OK.  That's a great start.  What does "Oracle doesn't like my method" mean, however?  Are you getting an error?  If so, what error?  Are you seeing (or not seeing) a behavior that you expect?  If so, what behavior is that?  It's really helpful to have a problem statement like "I run <<this SQL statement>>.  I expect that <<the statement will succeed/ I will get an error/ something else>>.  Instead, I see <<the statement errors/ the statement succeeds/ something else>>."

Comment: Says Warning: Trigger created with complication errors. Have 3 of them. Line/Col 5/1 SQL Statement ignored, 8/15 invalid relational operator, and 10/25 PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "THEN" when expecting one of th e following: ( - + all case mod new null <an identifier> < a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable> any av g count current max min prior some sql stddev sum variance exe cute forall merge time timestamp interval date <a string liter al with character set specification> <a number> <a single-quot ed SQL string> pipe <an alternatively-quoted string literal wi th

Comment: You'll want to edit your question to include the error stack.

Comment: You're missing an operator here: `where Mem-Num :new.Mem_num`

Comment: And here: `IF(NofTransactions+1) > then`

Comment: What kind of operator would I use? I guess im still a little bit lost on whats wrong

Comment: 'where Mem_Num :new.Mem_Num' for this part I am unsure on what to use for the operator. The 'IF(NofTransactions+1) > 5 then' part I just forgot the 5. Ive been looking in my oracle book and that doesn't really help whatsoever.

Comment: oh my gosh, did I just forget the '=' sign??? after the first Mem_Num...wow I feel like an idiot. Thanks for your help Jeffrey! Trigger Works now!